# Create a temporary version of file in use for my log viewer?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I've written an application that runs in the background and logs information to a file from different sources every 5 seconds.

I'm writing another application to act as a log viewer, but obviously I can't open the file as it's often in-use by the logger itself. Is there any way I can create a temporary copy of the log file for the viewer to use, which it can delete upon exit?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26528/C-Application-to-Watch-a-File-or-Directory-using-F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open file in both applications (logger and viewer) with [one of](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) overloaded methods, that accepts [FileShare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) parameter and set it to ReadWrite. Both programs then can use the same file at once.

Comment: They shouldn't need to both specify ReadWrite - the logger probably only wants to specify that Read sharing is allowed (so that no other process can also write to the log), whereas the log viewer may choose either ReadWrite or just Write (depending on whether other viewers should be allowed simultaneously).

Comment: You are right, viewer needs only Read sharing, I didn't want to complicate answer because ReadWrite should work fine as well.